# Create a total data with different subdata in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, octave, inner-classes

I have several data named `ET1_A_C1_l1`, `ET1_A_C2_l1`, `ET1_A_C3_l1`, ..., `ET1_A_C63_l1` in Workspace. Besides that,I also have another sets of data named `ET1_H_C1_l1`, `ET1_H_C2_l1`, ..., `ET1_A_C63_l1`

Now I need to combine 2 set of data into one named `Total_data.mat`; For example,

```
Total_data=[ET1_A_C1_l1 ET1_A_C2_l1 ET1_A_C3_l1 ..... ET1_A_63_l1;ET1_H_C1_l1 ET1_H_C2_l1 ....ET1_H_C63_l1]
```

and need to take a huge of time to type the code one by one. Is there any idea using the `loop` to do this??

Thanks.

Comment: Is `ET1_A_C1` a numeric matrix? What size? Are all the remaining variables also numeric matrices? Are they all the same size? This is necessary information to answer the question.

Comment: all the variables are 6x2 numeric matrix and both are the same size.

Comment: I've provided an answer. If it solves your problem then feel free to mark the question answered by clicking the tick mark next to my solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than jumping on my wagon straight away, I'll start with the solution (which has been set up with an example):

```
%# State the size of each matrix
T = 6; N = 2;

%# State the number of matrices in category A and H (63 in your case - but 2 in my example) 
K = 2;

%# Set up some example matrices
ET1_A_C1_l1 = rand(T, N); ET1_A_C2_l1 = 1 + rand(T, N);
ET1_H_C1_l1 = 2 + rand(T, N); ET1_H_C2_l1 = 3 + rand(T, N);

%# Preallocate a matrix to hold the output
M = NaN(2 * T, K * N);

%# Loop over the variables and add them to the matrix using the evil eval
for k = 1:K
    M(1:T, (k*N)-1:k*N) = eval(['ET1_A_C', num2str(k), '_l1']);
    M(T+1:2*T, (k*N)-1:k*N) = eval(['ET1_H_C', num2str(k), '_l1']);
end

%# Save to a mat file
save('Total_Data.mat', 'M');
```

Now, wagon time: If you've been given the data in the form that you have it now, and there was nothing you could do about it, and you realize what a terrible situation it is to be in, then you can stop reading now.

But, if you were responsible for creating all those E_blah variables in the first place, then you need to take a look at the answer of @jerad and start thinking about different ways of storing data. A cell array or a structure is one way to go about it. Or start with one big matrix in the first place. But remember the following two general rules:

1) If you have more than 20 variables in your workspace, then you're probably doing it wrong.

2) If you find yourself frequently using the evil function `eval` then you're almost definitely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Having this kind of problem suggests to me that you're not yet comfortable with the other data structures available in matlab... like cell arrays and structures. You could easily solve this problem by storing your data in a less arrays and then indexing them properly when needed.

Read about [structures (this tutorial is excellent)](http://yagtom.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/dataStructures.html) in the matlab documentation and then try to use one to store all of your data. I think that will solve this problem and many others you didn't know you had.

You should be using something like the following.

```
ET = struct;
ET.A.C(1) = ET1_A_C1;
ET.A.C(2)  = ET1_A_C2;
         ...
ET.A.C(N)  = ET1_A_CN;

ET.H.C(1)  = ET1_H_C1;
ET.H.C(2)  = ET1_H_C2;
          ...
ET.H.C(N)  = ET1_H_CN;
```

Now every thing is one variable which you can save without typing anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

`filename=Total_data.mat`;

```
for i=1:63
J(i,1)=ET1_A_C{i};
J(i,2)=ET1_H_C{i};
end
```

`save(filename,'J(1:63,1)','J(1:63,2)')`;

Comment: what is meant by { } in the code?? i change the data name to ET1_A_C1_l1 by adding the term '_l1' in each data,it will show the invalid characters and fail to run..

Comment: I didnt see the purpose of adding the '_I1'. Could you please tell its purpose? I actually gave a pseudocode like structure. its like you need to use eval command to convert the strings to variable name and then store the data in them.